# git: how to prevent people from deleting files not authored by them

Tags: git, gitlab

For our specific use case of git...

1. I need to prevent people from deleting files not authored by them. How can I do that? Maybe with hooks somehow?
2. Optional: some sort of "-force" cli parameter may allow such a deletion.
3. Preferably this feature should be passed along to the forks (on GitLab).
4. If preventing is not possible then at least how can I be warned on merge/pull that certain file was(or is about to be) deleted by somebody who has not authored it?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably doing something wrong here. Git and gitlab does not have this feature and you're trying to use a software in a way it wasn't designed for. This is usually a warning sign, maybe it's your internal process that needs to be changed instead.

Anyway, you're on the right track. You can almost achieve this with a hook. If you're a gitlab administrator (and hosting your own gitlab instance) you can setup what gitlab call custom git hooks (from gitlabs documentation):

> Setup
>
> Normally, git hooks are placed in the repository or project's hooks
> directory. GitLab creates a symlink from each project's hooks
> directory to the gitlab-shell hooks directory for ease of maintenance
> between gitlab-shell upgrades. As such, custom hooks are implemented a
> little differently. Behavior is exactly the same once the hook is
> created, though. Follow these steps to set up a custom hook.
>
> ```
> 1. Pick a project that needs a custom git hook.
> 2. On the GitLab server, navigate to the project's repository directory. For an installation from source the path is usually /home/git/repositories/<group>/<project>.git. For Omnibus installs the path is usually /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/<group>/<project>.git.
> 3. Create a new directory in this location called custom_hooks.
> 4. Inside the new custom_hooks directory, create a file with a name matching the hook type. For a pre-receive hook the file name should be pre-receive with no extension.
> 5. Make the hook file executable and make sure it's owned by git.
> 6. Write the code to make the git hook function as expected. Hooks can be in any language. Ensure the 'shebang' at the top properly
> ```
>
> reflects the language type. For example, if the script is in Ruby the
> shebang will probably be #!/usr/bin/env ruby.
>
> That's it! Assuming the hook code is properly implemented the hook
> will fire as appropriate.

I haven't tested but I don't think this hook will follow in forks, so then you'll have to modify the gitlab source code to make that happen.

Last gitlab tracks content and not files. For example file renames are not recorded by guessed and this can sometimes lead to strange results. I'm pretty sure you can find some edge case here where your approach will behave strange.